# Is it possible to pass an intent to a tab?

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I try to pass an intent to an action bar tab. 
I have a main activity where I build my ActionBar:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("MY TICKETS")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<ShowListFragment>(
                    this, "LISTVIEW", ShowListFragment.class));

    actionBar.addTab(tab);


    tab = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText("LAST DRAW")
        .setTabListener(new TabListener<ShowLastDrawFragment>(
                this, "SHOWVIEW", ShowLastDrawFragment.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

Now I want to pass some informations with the intent mechanism, is this possible?
Like:

```
intent.putExtra("intent", mySerializeable());
```

I would like to access the class inside my tab fragment with:

```
mySerializeable ms = (mySerializeable) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("intent");
```

I found something like setContent(Intent intent), but that only works with TabHost.
Is it generally possible what I am trying to do and when yes, how?